# Rust smartcore index out of bounds

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a decision tree using rust smartcore lib.

main:

```
extern crate csv;
extern crate ndarray;
extern crate ndarray_csv;

use smartcore::linalg::naive::dense_matrix::*;
use smartcore::tree::decision_tree_classifier::*;
use csv::ReaderBuilder;

use ndarray::Array2;
use ndarray_csv::Array2Reader;

fn main() {

let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new()
    .has_headers(true)
    .delimiter(b';')
    .from_path("./src/result.csv")
    .expect("can create reader");

let array: Array2<f64> = reader
    .deserialize_array2_dynamic()
    .expect("can deserialize array");


let data_set = DenseMatrix::from_array(
    array.shape()[0],
    array.shape()[1],
    &array.as_slice().unwrap()
);

let data = data_set.slice( 0..data_set.shape().0 , 0..3);
let targets = data_set.slice( 0..data_set.shape().0 , 3..6);

let tree = DecisionTreeClassifier::fit(&data, &targets.to_row_vector(), Default::default()).unwrap();
let _y_hat = tree.predict(&data).unwrap(); // use the same data for prediction

}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "RustTest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
smartcore = "0.2.0"
csv = "1.1.6"
ndarray-csv = "0.5.1"
ndarray = "0.15.4"
```

I'm getting

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 235200 but the index is 235200', /Users/Ezberci/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/smartcore-0.2.0/src/tree/decision_tree_classifier.rs:359:29 stack backtrace:    0:        0x101fa9e91 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h0b624e35bf84187c
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:93:5 1:        0x101fa9e91 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h435d9bd636904605
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5 2:        0x101fa9e91 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::h3ca407d645e7e73d
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:67:5 3:        0x101fa9e91 - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h4f26ffad025fdbe8
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:46:22 4:        0x101fc399b - core::fmt::write::h0a9937d83d3944c1
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1168:17 5:        0x101fa70e8 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::hfaf2e2e92eda8127
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1660:15 6:        0x101fabe27 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h11335bd900abe1ce
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:49:5 7:        0x101fabe27 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::hdf5291c87f745042
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:36:9 8:        0x101fabe27 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::hc11e9b8d348e68b0
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:211:50 9:        0x101faba35 - std::panicking::default_hook::h1d26ec4d0d63be04
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:228:9 10:        0x101fac4b0 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hef4f5e524db188b3
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:606:17 11:        0x101fac1de - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::h6e8805ea2351af89
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:502:13 12:        0x101faa307 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::hd383ade987b76f63
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:139:18 13:        0x101fabeca - rust_begin_unwind
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:498:5 14:        0x101fc9d0f - core::panicking::panic_fmt::hb58956db718d5b79
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/panicking.rs:116:14 15:        0x101fc9cd6 - core::panicking::panic_bounds_check::hb399dc81a1fa1f74
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/panicking.rs:84:5 16:        0x101f77136 - <usize as core::slice::index::SliceIndex<[T]>>::index::ha5785fd1643669bf
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/slice/index.rs:189:10 17:        0x101f77087 - core::slice::index::<impl core::ops::index::Index<I> for [T]>::index::h0f2c419b17bda497
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/slice/index.rs:15:9 18:        0x101f19eb8 - <alloc::vec::Vec<T,A> as core::ops::index::Index<I>>::index::hb9329b8fb73feeb1
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:2520:9 19:        0x101f375fb - smartcore::tree::decision_tree_classifier::DecisionTreeClassifier<T>::fit_weak_learner::h733186b4eeecad3a
       at /Users/Ezberci/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/smartcore-0.2.0/src/tree/decision_tree_classifier.rs:359:29 20:        0x101f36f24 - smartcore::tree::decision_tree_classifier::DecisionTreeClassifier<T>::fit::h17bbaa15ed674329
       at /Users/Ezberci/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/smartcore-0.2.0/src/tree/decision_tree_classifier.rs:326:9 21:        0x101f2e52b - RustTest::main::h7bebf0fe120ff244
       at /Users/Ezberci/Desktop/RustTest/src/main.rs:34:16   22:        0x101f339be - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h88e0f90abf56ec76
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:227:5 23:        0x101f29601 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::had3be60cba91effe
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:123:18 24:        0x101f23b54 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::habb4a06572314f48
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/rt.rs:145:18 25:        0x101fa959e - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::h1d1e9294d7151cb0
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259:13 26:        0x101fa959e - std::panicking::try::do_call::h315943602cc1e70c
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:406:40 27:        0x101fa959e - std::panicking::try::h5be753f80fffd492
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:370:19 28:        0x101fa959e - std::panic::catch_unwind::h9fdcb02c74b07e26
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panic.rs:133:14 29:        0x101fa959e - std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}::h1558447834abc29f
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:48 30:        0x101fa959e - std::panicking::try::do_call::h5721bf6e49d6926d
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:406:40 31:        0x101fa959e - std::panicking::try::hee7cffb35a5e550d
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:370:19 32:        0x101fa959e - std::panic::catch_unwind::hf45e91e6006ab16e
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panic.rs:133:14 33:        0x101fa959e - std::rt::lang_start_internal::h64086fc6655bfbe8
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/rt.rs:128:20 34:        0x101f23b2e - std::rt::lang_start::h8ea4706036a83281
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/rt.rs:144:17 35:        0x101f31ef6 - <unknown>
       at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/cmp.rs:1347:21

Process finished with exit code 101
```

I have 235201 line in the csv file. I don't have any empty line and even if I change the number of rows the error changes accordingly. How can I fix this error?

Comment: What line does the error happen on? Please provide a full backtrace.

Comment: I added the whole stack trace.

Comment: I don't really know anything about smartcore. You may want to add it as a trash on your question. I'm guessing that it's trying to access double or triple the amount of data you're providing, and just hits the first error there.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input data?